# download multiple files from a folder on web server

Tags: c++, web, client

I've built a web client in C++. The program is able to download types of files from web servers
Eg: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224w/slides/01-intro.pdf, http://www.google.com/index.html, ...

I'm now trying to build some methods to download all the files from a folder on web server.
Eg: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224w/slides/

But I just can't figure out how to access the url to the files. I've been searching for weeks but still stuck. Any way to approach ?
(This is the first time I ask question on the platform, so I'm sorry if the question is any weird or hard to understand.)

May be I should do something with the request handling code ?

```
// This is the function to handle the URL
void handleURL::Handler(std::string request, std::string& addr, std::string& pathToFile, std::string& downloadFile) {   
    // Remove "http://"
    if (request.substr(0, 7) == "http://") {
        request.erase(0, 7);
    }

    int n = request.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n && request[i] != '/'; i++) {
        addr += request[i];
    }

    // Validate download request 
    bool check = false;
    int indexStart = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (request[i] == '/') {
            check = true;
            indexStart = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (check) {
        for (int i = indexStart; i < n; i++) {
            pathToFile += request[i];
        }

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0 && request[i] != '/'; i--) {     
            std::string insertChar = "";
            insertChar += request[i];
            downloadFile.insert(0, insertChar);
        }
    }
}
```

```
// This is the request: 
std::stringstream request; 

request << "GET /" << pathToFile << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
request << "Host: " << addr << "\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Remember, the `".../slides/"` is just another webpage. Download that and parse for each of the href links and download each file

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I know that when we get to the /slides/ page, an html will be rendered, and there are <a>  tags which contain the links to the files, but somehow the request to download the index.html rendered on that page is failed, server response the 301 code.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. The slides page somehow just can't be found (too old I supppose)  that the server even responsed the 404 code. So I tried to download the webpage /cs224w/ which also contains links to the files, not the /slides/ route and successfully downloaded the html file.

Comment: But I still wonder why the server responsed 404 code when I request html file on /cs224w/slides/ route but worked with /cs224w/ ?